# Backbone model fetch is hitting cache instead of server (in phonegap)

Tags: cordova, backbone.js

I'm calling fetch on a model. Phone gap is returning a cached response instead of issuing a new request. (or maybe it's android that's caching...)

Can I override backbone.sync in such a way as to bust the cache problem from phonegap/android?

Alternatively, can I clear the cache manually from javascript?

Comment: It's very weird behavior that should to prove and to solve, but as a work around you can pass a _timestamp parameter_ in your Model url.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will want to look at the documented bugs in IOS6 with Ajax.

See: http://www.devthought.com/2012/09/22/understanding-the-ios6-ajax-bugs/